# How to move GitHub directory

Tags: git, github

I have formatted my laptop(window) and to use my gitHub repository again, what do I have to do?
Do I need to do something to reconnect my laptop folder and gitHub repository?

Secondly, if I want to move the local repository, what do I have to do?

for example, C:\dir1\dir2 -> C:\newDir1

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your issues seem not to be connected to the git. Git keeps the history in the hidden folder. When you move your repository folder, the hidden folder is moved as well. What did you try to do already to solve you problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move your local repository into any others directory. It will be same. It won't make difference. You can track them as before, because in that repository you have `.git` and by that you initialized git tracking for that repository.

By the way, if you want to use the repo in your new laptop(or new OS), you need to either clone that repo or after copying that folder you need to do git initialization by `git init` command.